# Rails undefined local variable or method: Rendering partial with join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, renderpartial

I have a joint table between company and other models like jobs, location, people

_companies.html.erb

```
    <% if company.companylogo %>
    <%= link_to (image_tag(company.companylogo.url(:medium), :class => "fw img-responsive", :alt =>"company logo")), company_path(company) %>
    <% else %> 
    <%= link_to (image_tag("http://via.placeholder.com/405x285", :class => "fw img-responsive", :alt =>"company logo")), company_path(company) %>
    <% end %>



   <p <%= link_to truncate(company.name, :length => 20), company_path(company), :class => "" %> </p>
```

in the job/index.html.erb I am able to render all content from the above company partial by

```
<%= render job.companies if job.companies.present? %>
```

Which shows the parent company logo and company name.

Now i want to separate the company name from the logo by creating another partial: 
_seperatename.html.erb

```
**<p <%= link_to truncate(company.name, :length => 20), company_path(company), :class => "" %> </p>**
```

**My question is, in the job/index.html.erb, how can I render _seperatename.html.erb ?**

I have tried <%= render 'companies/seperatename' %>

it throws error 
ActionView::Template::Error at /jobs
undefined local variable or method `company' for #<#:0x007f99b6b239f8>

However if I replace ruby content in the _seperatename.html.erb with a normal text it renders with no error

Comment: It's bit unclear what you are asking. But, I think you need `render partial: ...` [DOCS](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a variable to a partial:

```
<%= render partial: 'companies/seperatename', locals: {company: @company} %>
```

Docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials